# Nodejs Require Class returning {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

So I'm creating a singleton class and when I require it from my `server.js` file it works fine, but when I require it from another file it returns as undefined. I'll try to post relevant code but some will have to be cut out due to work.

server.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const config = require('config');
const FBConfigsListener = require('./server/amq_listeners/fb_configs.listener');
const FBConfigs = require('./server/models/FBConfigs');

//Api file for interacting with mongodb
const api = require('./server/routes/api.routes');

//Parsers
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Angular Dist output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

//Api location
app.use('/api', api);

//Send all  other requests to angular
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});

//set port
var port = config.get('webserver.port');
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

models/FBConfigs.js

```js
var ConfigModel = require('./config');
var config = require('config');
var _ = require('lodash');
var FBConfigsListener = require('../amq_listeners/fb_configs.listener');
var AMQAdapter = require('../adapters/amq.adapter');
var uniqid = require('uniqid');
const connectionOptions = config.get('activemq.connectionOptions');

class FBConfigs {
  constructor() {
    console.log(config.get('environments'));
    this.listener = FBConfigsListener;
    this.configs = {};
    this.unique_keys = ['id'];
    this.update_topic = '/topic/fusebuilder.update.config.';
    console.log(FBConfigsListener);
    //AMQ Client
    this.amq_client = AMQAdapter.getInstance(connectionOptions.host, connectionOptions.port);
  }

  add(key, config) {
    if (!(key in this.configs)) {
      this.configs[key] = new ConfigModel(this.unique_keys);
    }
    this.configs[key].add(config);
  }

  get(key) {
    let configs_json = {};
    if (key) {
      configs_json[key] = JSON.parse(this.configs[key].toString());
    } else {
      for (let key in this.configs) {
        configs_json[key] = JSON.parse(this.configs[key].toString());
      }
    }
    return configs_json;
  }

  updateByID(key, id, input_config) {
    let configs = this.configs[key].get();
    for (let config of configs) {
      if (input_config.id === config.id) {
        this.update(key, _.merge(config, input_config));
      }
    }
  }
  //Send update to config topic
  update(key, config) {
    let topic = this.update_topic + key;
    var update_object = {};
    if (Array.isArray(config)) {
      update_object[key] = [...config];
    } else {
      update_object[key] = [config];
    }
    console.log(`Sending ${key} update:${JSON.stringify(update_object)}`);
    this.amq_client.sendMessage(topic, update_object);
  }

  copyTo(key, id, env) {
    let selected_env = config.get('environments.' + env);
    // let tmp_amq_client = new AMQAdapter(selected_env.host, selected_env.port);
    let selected_config = this.configs[key].getByID(id);
    console.log(this);
    if (key === 'fuses') {
      console.log('In FBConfig Copy to for fuses');
      const get_fuse_topic = '/topic/fusebuilder.get_fuse';
      const tran_id = uniqid();
      const sendObj = { fuseName: id, tran_id };
      this.amq_client.sendMessage(get_fuse_topic, sendObj);
      var startTime = process.hrtime()[0];
      var timeout = false;
      while (!this.listener.get_copy_fuse_data(tran_id)) {
        console.log('Waiting for config');
        sleep(100);
        if (process.hrtime()[0] - startTime > 3) {
          console.log('Timed out');
          timeout = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(FBConfigsListener.get_copy_fuse_data(tran_id)));
    } else {
      tmp_amq_client.sendMessage(this.update_topic, selected_config);
    }

    console.log(`Copy ${key} id:${id} to ${env}`);
  }
}

module.exports = new FBConfigs();
```

amq_listener/fb_configs.listener.js

```js
const config = require('config');
var AMQAdapter = require('../adapters/amq.adapter');
var FBConfigs = require('../models/FBConfigs');
**removed for work**

class FBConfigsListener {
  constructor() {
    this.instance;
    this.copy_fuse_data = {};
    //AMQ Client
    this.amq_client = AMQAdapter.getInstance(connectionOptions.host, connectionOptions.port);
    //Subscribe to configs
    this.amq_client.subscribe(config_subscribe_topic, this.config_topic_callback.bind(this));
    //Request Tables
    this.amq_client.sendMessage(config_request_topic, { tables: config_tables });
    //Subscribe to Copy Fuse topic
    this.amq_client.subscribe(subscribe_fuse_copy_topic, this.copy_fuse_callback.bind(this));
  }

  config_topic_callback(err, message) {
    let dest = this.amq_client.getDestination(message);
    let key = this.get_key_from_topic(dest);
    this.amq_client.readMessage(message, body => {
      let configs = JSON.parse(body);
      if (key in configs) {
        for (let config of configs[key]) {
          FBConfigs.add(key, config);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  copy_fuse_callback(err, message) {
    this.amq_client.readMessage(message, body => {
      const config = JSON.parse(body);
      this.copy_fuse_data[config.tran_id] = config;
    });
  }

  //Get Key from the topic and convert using key map if needed
  get_key_from_topic(topic) {
    let key = topic.split('.')[topic.split('.').length - 1];
    key = key in key_map ? key_map[key] : key;
    return key;
  }

  get_copy_fuse_data(id) {
    if (id in this.copy_fuse_data) {
      return this.copy_fuse_data[id];
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

module.exports = new FBConfigsListener();
```

Error happens in `FBConfigs`. `FBConfigsListener` returns `{}` so all functions in there are undefined. Even if I do `console.log(require('../amq_listeners/fb_configs.listener'))` it prints `{}` But doing the same thing in `server.js` (with updated path) it prints the module.

Also tips on how to improve my coding style would be appreciated too.

**Edit**
So I found out that I have a circular dependency between these classes. How can this be fixed while allowing me to call one from the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to instantiate your dependencies firstly and store them in some object which you can pass then to your dependent classes. The structure can be

factories/services.js

```
/*
 * Instantiates passed services and passes injector object to them
 */
module.exports = function createServices(injector, services) {
  return Object.entries(services)
    .reduce((aggregator, [name, serv]) => {
      const name_ = camelCase(name);

      aggregator.set(name_, new serv(injector));

      return aggregator;
  }, new Map());
};
```

lib/service.js

```
/**
 * Base class for classes need any injections
 */
module.exports = class Service {
  constructor(injector) {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  get dependencies() {
    return this.injector.dependencies;
  }

  /*
   * Background jobs can be ran here
   */
  async startService() {}

  /*
   * Background jobs can be stopped here
   */
  async stopService() {}
};
```

lib/injector.js

```
const Service = require('./service');

/*
 * Contains all dependencies
 */
module.exports = class Injector {
  constructor() {
    this.services = new Map();
    this._dependencies = {};
  }

  has(name) {
    return this.services.has(name);
  }

  register(name, service) {
    if (this.has(name)) {
      throw new Error(`Service ${name} already exists`);
    }

    if (service instanceof Service === false) {
      throw new Error('Argument #2 should be an instance of Service');
    }

    this.services.set(name, service);
    this._dependencies[name] = service;
  }

  unregister(name) {
    if (! this.has(name)) {
      throw new Error(`Service ${name} not found`);
    }

    this.services.delete(name);
    delete this._dependencies[name];
  }

  get dependencies() {
    return { ...this._dependencies };
  }

  /*
   * Starts all registered services
   */
  async start() {
    for (let service of this.services.values()) {
      await service.startService();
    }
  }

  /*
   * Stops all registered services
   */
  async stop() {
    for (let service of this.services.values()) {
      await service.stopService();
    }
  }
};
```

Then import, initialize and bind your services in the main file (don't forget to export just a class, not an object like you do it now).

server.js

```
const createServices = require('./factories/services.js');
const injector = require('./lib/injector');
const Injector = new injector();

const services = createServices(Injector, [require('./server/amq_listeners/fb_configs.listener'), require('./server/models/FBConfigs')]);

services.forEach((service, name) => {
  Injector.register(name, service);
});

// Start services
Injector.start();
```

Inherit required classes to `Service` class and you will get an access to all dependencies there (don't forget to call `super()` from constructor). Like

models/FBConfigs.js

```
const Service = require('../lib/service');    

class FBConfigs extends Service {
  constructor(injector) {
     super(injector);
     const { FBConfigsListener } = this.dependencies;
     ...your code here
  }

  async startService() {
    ...run bg job or init some connection
  }

  async stopService() {
    ...stop bg job or close some connection
  }
}

module.exports = FBConfigs;
```

Also you can pass some config object to `createServices` (I didn't include it here) with keys equal to service names and values containing config object and pass config to appropriate service.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I will give it a shot!

Comment: @Ponzi314 if this answer solves your problem, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: no problems. Tell me if you need some clarifications.

Comment: @Revinand what do i do if i want the class to be a singleton though? Is this still valid? I dont want to keep making new instances or either FBConfigs or FBConfigsListener because they run in background collecting data from active mq. Does this solution work that way? would I do like what im doing now which is export the Object?

Comment: All classes will be initialized only once in the `createServices` function and their instances will be stored in a single `Injector` object. As long as you access them through `Injector` instance they will point to the same `Service` instances. I'll supplement the answer with possibility to start/stop services.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by that circular dependency. You should avoid it or used very carefully.

In your case the fix is probably pretty simple, move the line `var FBConfigs = require('../models/FBConfigs');` from listener at the end of the file as the last line (yes, even after the module.exports).

---

Edit: Actually it maybe is not enough as I checked the code more in detail. As you are not using Listener in FBConfig constructor, you can create method `assignListener`, remove `this.listener` from that constructor and call it later in `server.js` which will do the `this.listener`

---

Or the last solution, which is also "best practice". Do not export the instances. Export the classes only. Then in server.js create these instances after both are required.

Comment: I only exported the Object because i was trying to create a singleton. I did however move the require below the module.exports and it started working. But Im going to try whats posted above just so i follow best practice.